# Adjusting Axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, axis, imdb

When creating my graph using Matplotlib, I have coded it to automatically size the axis as follows:

```
plt.axis([(int(yearofreleaselist[oldestfilm])-1), (int(yearofreleaselist[0]))+1, 0, (max(profits))+50000000])
```

However, dealing with large figures, the profits only displays a single digit with various shorthand references, as seen on this example graph:

[image: Example Graph]

The year of release also doesn't plot correctly, but some results are displayed properly, as seen here:

[image: As seen here]

I'm wondering how to fix this so the numbers are displayed correctly all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the offset ([see documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/api/ticker_api.html))

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

years = np.arange(2011,2016,1)
profit = np.random.random(years.size)

pl.figure()
ax=pl.subplot(121)
pl.scatter(years, profit)
ax=pl.subplot(122)
pl.scatter(years, profit)
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

[image]

Or, to set it for all figures/axes:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False
```