# How matplotlib show obvious changes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a pictrue with matplotlib. The y value is large,but the change of y is too small.For example,y = 1270000,but just has a change change range [-10,10].How could i show obvious changes of y?The pictrue could not show changes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Yq3.png)

Comment: So the entire function or all of the data is within the range 1270000 +/- 10 (for example)?

Comment: Matplotlib is trying to do what you need. That number at the top means the y scale goes from 0 + 1,269,990 to 20+1,269,990. There might be something else wrong - can you show some code?

Comment: You can disable the scaling/offset if you want and zoom the axis to an appropriate scale; see [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/api/ticker_api.html) or e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799915/adjusting-axis-in-matplotlib/33806252#33806252) post

Comment: Yes.All  data is in the range.I'll read the documents with more patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.randint(1270000-10, 1270000+10, x.size)

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(121)
pl.plot(x,y)
pl.ylim(y.min()-1, y.max()+1)

pl.subplot(122)
pl.plot(x,y)
pl.ylim(y.min()-1, y.max()+1)
ax=pl.gca()
ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

The last line disables the offset, which (in my opinion) creates a better readable figure. I don't want to translate a number in scientific notation plus an offset from that number to be able to read the value of some point in a plot.

[image]

Comment: Thx，the second one helped me a lot.